# auto.arima not parallelizing

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm attempting to speed up a slow `auto.arima` function by running it on a computer with 4 dual-core CPUs (I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and R 2.15.2).  The function is fitting a time series with 350,000 data points and roughly 50 exogenous variables.  I'm using the below code

```
fit<-auto.arima(orders,xreg=exogen, stepwise=FALSE, parallel=TRUE, num.cores=4)
```

However, I have multiple CPUs (each with multiple cores), not just one CPU with multiple cores. In case R was smart enough to get around this cores/CPUs differentiation, I took a look at my resource monitor and saw this:

[image]

which shows that only CPU3 is maxed out.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?  Does the `forecast` package work with `DoSNOW`?

Comment: Which package are you using? Most likely there is something wrong with your parallel environment, because most parallel implementations run the code on one core if something is not working eg. mclapply switch to lapply.

As a workaround you can try (using the `parallel` package)
`mclapply(order, auto.arima, xreg=exogen, stepwise=FALSE, parallel=FALSE, mc.cores=2)`

Answer (score 3):

Try `num.cores=8` and `num.cores=7`, use `system.time()` to see which one runs faster. If I remember correctly, R treats 1 core as one CPU. You have 8 cores, if I understood you correctly: "4 dual-core CPUs".